# How to use regex_replace_once (l3regex) for replacing in nested environments/macros?

Tags: environments, expl3, l3regex, regular-expressions

I am trying to have nested environments, where the outer applies some changes to the output of the inner one. Problem appears when the outer environment needs to use regex commands (regex_replace_once in my case) to modify partially the output of the inner environment. For example, if the inner environment changes its content to italic case and the outer environment changes the first letter to bold, then the combined nested version should make the whole thing italic and the first letter bold (bold-italic).

The problem is that normal regex would  match the environment name (such as matching `envname` in `\begin{envname}`) before matching the actual text. I tried to use different category matching in expl3, using \cX, \c[....], to avoid this matching but no success. Using `tl_analysis_show` shows that the category of the environment name in the `\begin{inner}` is character, so not recognizable from the rest of the text.

How one can use regex commands to change output of the nested environment without messing with control sequences (not only in the begining as in my case, but anywhere in the passed body argument)?

PS: A more generic form of this question, might be "how one can have cascading styles similar to CSS in HTML"

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\RequirePackage{expl3}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{outerenv}{+b}{%
    
    \tl_set:Nn \l_outerenv_body_tl {#1}
    % \regex_set:Nn \l_outerenv_pattern_regex {(\w)(.*)}
    % \regex_set:Nn \l_outerenv_pattern_regex {(\c[LO]\w)(.*)}
    \regex_set:Nn \l_outerenv_pattern_regex {(\c[^CBEMTPUDSOA]\w)(.*)}

    \tl_analysis_show:n {#1}

    \tl_analysis_show:N \l_outerenv_body_tl

    \regex_replace_once:NnN \l_outerenv_pattern_regex { \c{textbf}\cB\{ \1 \cE\} \2 } \l_outerenv_body_tl

    \tl_analysis_show:N \l_outerenv_body_tl

    \tl_use:N \l_outerenv_body_tl
}{}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{innerenv}{+b}{%

    \tl_set:Nn \l_innerenv_body_tl {\textit{#1}}
    \tl_analysis_show:N \l_innerenv_body_tl
        \tl_use:N \l_innerenv_body_tl
}{}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}


    \begin{innerenv}
        Inner is italic.
    \end{innerenv}

    \begin{outerenv}
        Outer's first letter is bold.
    \end{outerenv}


    \begin{outerenv}
        \begin{innerenv}
            Inner nested in the outer.
        \end{innerenv}
    \end{outerenv}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You have to write code to parse the tokens manually (and even that is not completely foolproof) -- for more complex macros I'd recommend using Lua to write the macro however.

Comment: @user202729, the point is that this MWE is just an example. I was expecting to be able to freely cascade styles (much like CSS) without concerning which environment is nested in which other one. That kind of parsing probably just fix the problem for specific cases.

Comment: As far as I know things like e.g. nesting \textbf in \emph TeX can do, but things like making the first letter bold you have no choice apart from writing parser.

Comment: Although maybe take a look at [formatting - Automatic bold for every first character of a line - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192467/automatic-bold-for-every-first-character-of-a-line) and see if you can pick any useful parser macro.