# What is the right way of cascading styles using nested environments/macros, while each environment/macro might partially stylize its embedded content?

Tags: environments, expansion, catcodes, nesting, l3regex

I have asked similar to this question [before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/641244/how-to-use-regex-replace-once-l3regex-for-replacing-in-nested-environments-mac?noredirect=1#comment1598436_641244), but I think I have to describe it in another way.

### Need

What is the right way of cascading styles using nested environments/macros (much like the way CSS works in HTML), while each environment might selectively and partially (not totally) stylize its embedded content?

### Problem

Let's say `innerenv` is nested in `outerenv`. If `innerenv` changes the text to be italic and `outerenv` makes it red, since they apply non-overlapping styles over the *whole* text, then naturally they work together (red italic).

However, if the the `outerenv` wants to modify a part (not the whole) of its embedded text (such as making the first letter bold, or the first three words in small caps, …) then it becomes problematic. The problem is that I could not find a way to recognize the expanded texts from control sequences. For example, the difference between `myenv` and `mytext` in `\begin{myenv}mytext\end{myenv}` seems to be unrecognizable.

### Tried solution

I tried to use `\regex_replace_once` with its extended feature of recognizing cat-codes, however as in the MWE below the `innerenv` in `\begin{innerenv}` is simply a character and not recognizable.

### Motivation

I am trying to translate *asciidoc* into latex. Asciidoc translates (using *Asciidoctor*) into HTML (and ePub, Docbook, direct PDF, ...) where (multiple) *roles* for block or inline elements get translated into CSS *classes* and cascade after each other. A latex translation needs to handle assigning multiple *roles* (I considered environments in latex) without creating errors nor it should cancel inner environment impacts. But as the MWE below shows, it does not work like that.

### MWE output

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\RequirePackage{expl3}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}



\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{outerenv}{+b}{%
    
    \tl_set:Nn \l_outerenv_body_tl {#1}
    % \regex_set:Nn \l_outerenv_pattern_regex {(\w)(.*)} % tried this, no success
    % \regex_set:Nn \l_outerenv_pattern_regex {(\c[LO]\w)(.*)} % tried this, no success
    \regex_set:Nn \l_outerenv_pattern_regex {(\c[^CBEMTPUDSOA]\w)(.*)} % tried this, no success

    \tl_analysis_show:N \l_outerenv_body_tl

    % \tl_set:Nn \l_outerenv_body_tl {\color{red}#1} % kind of change that works naturally on embeded things
    \regex_replace_once:NnN \l_outerenv_pattern_regex { \c{textbf}\cB\{ \1 \cE\} \2 } \l_outerenv_body_tl % but this does not work

    \tl_analysis_show:N \l_outerenv_body_tl

    \tl_use:N \l_outerenv_body_tl
}{}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{innerenv}{+b}{%

    \tl_set:Nn \l_innerenv_body_tl {\textit{#1}}
    \tl_analysis_show:N \l_innerenv_body_tl
        \tl_use:N \l_innerenv_body_tl
}{}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}


    \begin{innerenv}
        This is innerenv (italic).
    \end{innerenv}

    \begin{outerenv}
        This is outerenv (red text or first letter is bold).
    \end{outerenv}


    \begin{outerenv}
        \begin{innerenv}
            The innerenv nested in the outerenv.
        \end{innerenv}
    \end{outerenv}


\end{document}
```

Comment: If the translator is not inside LaTeX anyway, you can just use the translator itself to write out the commands manually (e.g. `\textbf{O}uter`) that should be faster and less of a headache than doing it in LaTeX... as long as you already have a ASCIIdoc parser.

Comment: @user202729, a translator needs to translate any Asciidoc document with arbitrary and user-defined roles, options, and attributes (that is the advantage of Asciidoc over, let's say, Markdown).  For this reason, the exact translation of the those roles or options cannot be done directly in the translator. It needs , still user defined, environments/macros in the Tex side with the same name (and similar functionality).