# Acrostic Environment

Tags: environments, poetry

I tried to wrote the code of an environment for [acrostics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acrostic), using [cenverse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/192442/59415) and [boldfirst](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/192468/59415), but it doesn't work (probably because *cenverse* use `//` and *boldfirst* not).

```
\newcommand\dob[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newenvironment{boldfirst}{\obeylines\everypar{\dob}}{}

\newenvironment{acrostic}[1]
{
    \begin{midpage}

        \def\cenverse#1\\{\settowidth{\versewidth}{#1}\begin{verse}[\versewidth]#1\\}

            \begin{boldfirst}
            }{
            \end{boldfirst}

        \end{verse}

    \end{midpage}

    \newpage
}
```

The final result must be one acrostic in the centre of every page, with the first letter of every line in bold. Each first letter must be aligned with the upper and the lower letters.

Example of the use:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{midpage}
\usepackage{microtype}

\newcommand\dob[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newenvironment{boldfirst}{\obeylines\everypar{\dob}}{}


\newenvironment{acrostic}[1]
{
    \begin{midpage}

        \def\cenverse#1\\{\settowidth{\versewidth}{#1}\begin{verse}[\versewidth]#1\\}

            \begin{boldfirst}
            }{
            \end{boldfirst}

        \end{verse}

    \end{midpage}

    \newpage
}

\begin{document}

\begin{acrostic}
Elizabeth it is in vain you say
Love not—thou sayest it in so sweet a way:
In vain those words from thee or L.E.L.
Zantippe's talents had enforced so well:
Ah! if that language from thy heart arise,
Breath it less gently forth—and veil thine eyes.
Endymion, recollect, when Luna tried
To cure his love—was cured of all beside—
His follie—pride—and passion—for he died.
\end{acrostic}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please always make examples full documents from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` so that people can use them to see the problem.

Comment: I edited the answer!

Comment: More on acrostics at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121440/tex-assistance-in-writing-hidden-acrostics

Answer (score 5):

An easy change in my code for your similar question allows to get the widest line for setting `\versewidth` (actually, there will be a tiny offset due to the bold first letter, but it's negligible).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{environ,expl3,verse,midpage}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron{boldfirst}{%
  \user_boldfirst:V \BODY
}

\seq_new:N \l__user_lines_seq
\seq_new:N \l__user_aline_seq
\tl_new:N \l__user_firstword_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \user_boldfirst:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__user_lines_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  \dim_zero:N \versewidth
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__user_lines_seq
   {
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { ##1 }
    \dim_compare:nT { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box > \versewidth }
     { \dim_set:Nn \versewidth { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box } }
   }
  \begin{verse}[\versewidth]
  \seq_map_function:NN \l__user_lines_seq \__user_bolden_line:n
  \end{verse}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \user_boldfirst:n { V }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__user_bolden_line:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__user_aline_seq {~} { #1 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__user_aline_seq \l__user_firstword_tl
  \__user_print_first:V \l__user_firstword_tl
  \seq_use:Nn \l__user_aline_seq { ~ } \\
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__user_print_first:n #1
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { \tl_count:n { #1 } == 1 }
   {
    \textbf{#1} ~ %
   }
   {
    \__user_bfkern:nnw #1 \q_stop
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__user_print_first:n { V }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__user_bfkern:nnw #1 #2 #3 \q_stop
 {
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { #1 #2 }
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpb_box { #1 \kern0pt #2 }
  \textbf{#1}\kern\dim_eval:n { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box - \box_wd:N \l_tmpb_box } 
  #2 #3 ~ %
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{midpage}

\begin{boldfirst}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \\
consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod \\
tempor incidunt ut labore \\
et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim \\
ad minim veniam, quis nostrud \\
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid \\
ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute \\
iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit \\
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. \\
{\^{E}}xcepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, \\
sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt \\
mollit anim id est laborum. \\
T{}o show kern \\
To show kern \\
A problem is not here
\end{boldfirst}

\end{midpage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I add this [ http://goo.gl/eGktXs ] after `\ExplSyntaxOff` and then I use `\begin{acrostic} ...acrostic... \end{acrostic}`, why it doesn't work?

Comment: @user Because you're not defining an environment correctly.

Comment: This [ http://goo.gl/hjJM0M ] is correct, I think, but it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: @user That seems correct, but "it doesn't work" means too little.

Comment: It returns error like this `LaTeX Error: \begin{boldfirst} on input line 121 ended by \end{ac rostic}.`, `LaTeX Error: \begin{midpage} on input line 143 ended by \end{docu ment}.`, etc. and the result is all the acrostics in a single page.

Comment: @user You have spurious characters: you can see them in your last comment, can't you?

Comment: What is a spurious characters?

Comment: @user The information you give is insufficient to make a diagnosis, sorry.

Comment: Here the complete code: http://goo.gl/LRgSeH and here the errors: http://goo.gl/kHMHjR.

Comment: @user Since `boldfirst` is defined with `\NewEnviron`, you have to use `\midpage\boldfirst` instead of `\begin{midpage}\begin{boldfirst}` and `\endmidpage\endboldfirst` instead of `\end{midpage}\end{boldfirst}`